# Angular material layout isn't consistent

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design, material-design, angular-material

I'm having problem with designing simple form.

```
<div layout="column" ng-cloak>
    <md-content class="md-padding">
        <form name="search">
            <md-input-container>
                <label>From where?</label>
                <input name="from" ng-model="from" required>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container>
                <label>To where?</label>
                <input name="to" ng-model="to" required>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-datepicker ng-model="date" md-placeholder="When?" ng-required="true" required></md-datepicker>
            <md-input-container>
                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Search</md-button>
            </md-input-container>
        </form>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

This is how it looks, I don't know am I doing something wrong? I'm new to this framework. I want all inputs to be aligned to same base line, and I wan't to add icons in front of text inputs.

[image: HTML preview]

Comment: inspect live html. underneath inputs are some extra error elements. I also found this out the hard way and had to tweak margins. Feature I didn't like and should be configurable

Answer (score 1):

There are known issues with input alignment at the moment. You would have to tweak some margins if you want to align it yourself.

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6636

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6219

You can get icons in the input containers by specifying a `<md-icon>`.

```
<md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block">
      <label>Name</label>
      <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_person_24px.svg" class="name"></md-icon>
      <input ng-model="user.name" type="text">
</md-input-container>
```

Check the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input) for more input examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure has only one `md-content` under the `layout="column"`. To stack the `md-input-container` and `md-datepicker` items you would need to add `layout="column"` to the `form` tag `<form name="search" layout="column">`which is the tag that is the parent to the tags your want to stack in a column.

```
<div layout="column" ng-cloak>
  <md-content  class="md-padding">
    <form name="search" layout="column">
      <md-input-container>
        <label>From where?</label>
        <input name="from" ng-model="from" required>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>To where?</label>
        <input name="to" ng-model="to" required>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="date" md-placeholder="When?" ng-required="true" required></md-datepicker>
      <md-input-container>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Search</md-button>
      </md-input-container>
    </form>
  </md-content>
</div>
```